# Go Lang Unit Test

Tags: postgresql, rest, unit-testing, go

Getting error Of primary key violation user_id while running a unit test

My function for togglefavourite is as below

```
func ToggleTrackToFavourite(c *gin.Context) {
    userID := GetCurrentUserID(c)
    trackID, err := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Invalid Track ID"})
        return
    }
    if err := favourites.CreateTable(db.DB); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to create table" + err.Error()})
        return
    }
    if isInFavorites(userID, trackID) {
        err = favourites.RemoveFavorite(db.DB, userID, trackID)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to remove track from favorites"})
            return
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Track removed from favorites"})
    } else {
        err = favourites.InsertFavorite(db.DB, userID, trackID)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to add track to favorites : " + err.Error()})
            return
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Track added to favorites"})
    }
}
```

```
func GetCurrentUserID(c *gin.Context) int {
    userID, exists := c.Get("userID")
    if !exists {
        return 0
    }
    if userIDInt, ok := userID.(int); ok {
        return userIDInt
    }
    return 0
}
```

my unit test function for the above code is as below

```
func TestToggleTrackToFavourite(t *testing.T) {
    db.InitTestDB()

    if err := users.CreateTable(db.DB); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to create users table: %v", err)
    }
    if err := tracks.CreateTable(db.DB); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to create tracks table: %v", err)
    }
    if err := favourites.CreateTable(db.DB); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to create favorites table: %v", err)
    }
    user := users.User{
        Username: "Test",
        Email:    "test@gmail.com",
        Password: "123456",
    }
    if err := users.CreateUser(db.DB, &user); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to create user: %v", err)
    }

    sampleTrack := tracks.Track{
        Name:         "Test track",
        Index:        10,
        Track:        "chere.mp4",
        Image:        "image.jpg",
        Album_ID:     4,
        Is_Published: true,
    }
    if err := tracks.CreateTrack(db.DB, &sampleTrack); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to insert the example track: %v", err)
    }

    r := gin.Default()
    r.PUT("/user/favorite/toggle/:id", ToggleTrackToFavourite)

    reqAddToFavorites := httptest.NewRequest("PUT", "/user/favorite/toggle/1", nil)
    wAddToFavorites := httptest.NewRecorder()

    r.ServeHTTP(wAddToFavorites, reqAddToFavorites)
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, wAddToFavorites.Code)
    assert.Equal(t, `{"message":"Track added to favorites"}`, wAddToFavorites.Body.String())

    // reqRemoveFromFavorites := httptest.NewRequest("PUT", "/user/favorite/toggle/1", nil)
    // reqAddToFavorites.Params = append(reqAddToFavorites.Params, httptest.Param{"id", "1"})
    // wRemoveFromFavorites := httptest.NewRecorder()
    // r.ServeHTTP(wRemoveFromFavorites, reqRemoveFromFavorites)
    // assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, wRemoveFromFavorites.Code)
    // assert.Equal(t, `{"message":"Track removed from favorites"}`, wRemoveFromFavorites.Body.String())

    if _, err := db.DB.Exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favorite"); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to drop the table: %v", err)
    }
    if _, err := db.DB.Exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tracks"); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to drop the table: %v", err)
    }
    if _, err := db.DB.Exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users"); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to drop the table: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Not getting idea of how to pass the default value of GETCURRENTUSER function as 1 in the unit test

Want to just add/remove track from favourite

Comment: You create your user but never associate it with the request. Either you should use an authentication middleware and pass a header or cookie in your test, or set the context directly in the unit test (never used Gin, not sure if that's possible).

Comment: does your `User` struct include some kind of `UserId` attribute?  Can you set `user := users.User{ userId: 1, ... }`?

Comment: no my User struct does not use UserId  i just want to set the value of my GetCurrentUserID function (which is getting the value from the middleware ) to 1 so that i can pass the unit test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that user id in your code is stored in local variable named "userId" in context locals in some authentication middle-ware before your handler, so setting it is enough for testing, you can change these lines:

```
    r := gin.Default()
    c.Set("userID", "1")
    r.PUT("/user/favorite/toggle/:id", ToggleTrackToFavourite)
```